# Ambiguous when two superclasses have a  member function with the same name, but different signatures

Tags: c++, templates, class-hierarchy

```
struct A {
    void f(int x) {}
};

struct B {
    template<typename T> void f(T x) {}
};

struct C : public A, public B {};

struct D {
    void f(int x){}
    template<typename T> void f(T x) {} 
};


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    C c;
    c.f<int>(3);
    D d;
    d.f<int>(3);
}
```

What is the reason for which calling `d.f` is fine, but `c.f` gives

```
error: request for member ‘f’ is ambiguous
error: candidates are: template<class T> void B::f(T)
error:                 void A::f(int)
```

Comment: Good question. I guess usual overload resolution rules do not apply in `C` (since normally non templates are preferred to templates if there is a match, hence the behavior with `D`).

Comment: I would add to the OP's question: "whatever C++ standard rule enforces such a behaviour: what is the rationale behind this rule?"

Comment: @Vlad I think the behavior is quite sensible. Not causing an error here could lead the way to many nasty bugs. Good question though.

Comment: @enobayram: then, why there's no error for `C::f`?

Comment: are you sure the compiler is not stopping after first error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first part is due to member name lookup, that's why it fails.

I would refer you to: `10.2/2 Member name lookup`

> The following steps define the result of name lookup in a class scope,
>   C. First, every declaration for the name in the class and in each of
>   its base class sub-objects is considered. A member name f in one
>   sub-object B hides a member name f in a sub-object A if A is a base
>   class sub-object of B. Any declarations that are so hidden are
>   eliminated from consideration. Each of these declarations that was
>   introduced by a using-declaration is considered to be from each
>   sub-object of C that is of the type containing the declaration
>   designated by the using-declaration.
>
> **If the resulting set of declarations are not all from sub-objects of
>   the same type, or the set has a nonstatic member and includes members
>   from distinct sub-objects, there is an ambiguity and the program is
>   ill-formed**. Otherwise that set is the result of the lookup.

Now, for the matter with template functions.

As per `13.3.1/7 Candidate functions and argument list`

> In each case where a candidate is a function template, candidate
>   function template specializations are generated using template
>   argument deduction (14.8.3, 14.8.2). Those candidates are then handled
>   as candidate functions in the usual way. A given name can refer to one
>   or more function templates and also to a set of overloaded
>   non-template functions. In such a case, the candidate functions
>   generated from each function template are combined with the set of
>   non-template candidate functions.

And if you continue reading `13.3.3/1 Best viable function`

F1 is considered to be a *better* function, if:

> F1 is a non-template function and F2 is a function template
>   specialization

That's why the following snippet compiles and runs the non-template function without error:

```
D c;
c.f(1);
```

Comment: but why does the compiler see only `A::f`, but not `B::f`? Where is the namespace difference?

Comment: Can you back this up with a quote from the standard?

Comment: Currently I'm working under the assumption that it ignores all other base members, as soon as it finds one. Would be intresting to know if you can control which is being invoked by changing the order of inheritance, e.g. `struct C : public B, public A`

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I'm looking for it.

Comment: @John: In your quote, I cannot find what makes the compiler eliminate either of the `f`'s in the case of `struct C`.

Comment: @Vlad: The compiler does not eliminate either of them in the case of `C`; the second paragraph applies, and the program is ill-formed because they are not all from sub-objects of the same type.

Comment: My bad, I got a bit confused by the question at first, but I think I managed to put all the pices together in the end.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Thanks, I had failed to grasp the point of that paragraph.

Comment: @John: well, then I would repeat my question from the comments to the original post: what is the rationale behind such a rule? Does it makes any sense for struct `C` behave different from `D`?

Comment: Unfortunatly I cannot answer that, but I would think it has to due with complexity. Basically, to prevent language abuse. Think of it like this, if you introduce members in a base class that would pollute all derrived classes and possibly break code. That really should result in a compiler error becuase the rules you based that first program on, just changed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the compiler prefers `A::f` (non-template function) over `B::f` for no reason.
This seems to be a compiler **implementation bug** more than a implementation dependent detail.

If you add following line, then [compilation goes fine](http://ideone.com/bGtqF) and the correct function `B::f<>` is selected:

```
struct C : public A, public B { 
  using A::f; // optional
  using B::f;
};
```

[Funny part is that until the `::f` are not brought into the scope of `C`, they are treated as alien functions.]

Comment: Iteresting still, if we comment out `using A::f;` A::f is hidden by B::f, whereas with both `using` declarations `c.f<int>(3)` and `c.f(3)` correctly call corresponding functions.

Comment: Except the compiler doesn't prefer `A::f` - it considers both, and fails due to the ambiguity.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, then the question is why compiler doesn't have such ambiguity in the case of `D::f` ? In this case, it seems to be a case of preference to me.

Comment: @iammilind: Indeed; in the case of `D`, both names are considered, and the template specialisation is preferred to the non-template. I was commenting on your statement that "the compiler prefers `A::f` over `B::f`", which is wrong - in that case, it does not prefer either, hence the ambiguity error.

Answer (score 0):

A compiler doesn't know which method to call from the C class because templated method will be transormed in void f(int) in case of int type so you have two methods with the same name and same arguments but members of different parent classes.

```
template<typename T> void f(T x) {}
```

or

```
void f(int)
```

try this:

```
c.B::f<int>(3);
```

or this for the A class:

```
c.A::f(3);
```

Comment: The OP's question is not _how_, it's _why_?

Comment: The answer for a why is:A compiler doesn't know which method to call from the C class

Comment: Ok... why does it know for class D?

Comment: I guess that a compiler will apply the template construction before the inheritance. B and A classes will be compiled first and after that the inheritance on C class will be applied.

Comment: @Alex: No, this won't work. How would the compiler see the templated overload _before_ applying inheritance?

Comment: Interesting, the problem goes away if I say `using A::f; using B::f;` inside `C`s declaration.

Comment: @Vlad I believe that by reading the C class first it assumes that it needs to generate a B<int> class after that compiler apply the inheritance like class C: public A, public B<int> but here you have a problem because of 2 same methods.

Comment: @Alex: well, `B` is not templated, just `B::f` is. But anyway, after applying inheritance, what is the difference now between `C` and `D`? They now look the same for the compiler, right?

Comment: @Vlad: Sorry for the mistake of template class you are right is just a templated method but it doesn't matter. No C and D are very different classes C class is a child of two base classes and D is just one class and methods implementation in case of C class is still in B and A classes with a difference of D class.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this simpler example:

```
struct A{
 void f(int x){}
};

struct B{
 void f(float t){}
};


struct C:public A,public B{
};

struct D{
 void f(float n){}
 void f(int n){}
};


int main(){
 C c;
 c.f(3);

 D d;
 d.f(3);
}
```

In this example, same as yours, `D` compiles but `C` does not. 
If a class is a derived one, member lookup mechanism behaves different. It checks each base class and merges them: In the case of `C`; Each base class matches the lookup ( A::f(int) and B::f(float) ). Upon merging them `C` decides they are ambiguous.

For the case class `D`: `int` version is selected instead of `float` because parameter is an integer.

Comment: Thank you, this supports the thesis that when it does not find the method, it goes up to the superclasses, generate all the possibilities and complain if there're multiple choices.
as @jammilind and jrok point out, with using it generates them beforehand, and checks the best matching one

Comment: This is just an observation. Without a supporting quote from the standard, it's useless. It could be a compiler bug.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore yes,this is why I am waiting in toggling the accepted answer tick

Comment: @FabioDallaLibera as well you should. The question is a very good one and I, for one, think it deserves a matching answer.

Comment: It can be observed at C++ standard member name lookup section (class.member.lookup item 6 ). Sorry i cannot copy here but it also contains good description better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

What is probably happening is that the template instantiation is happening separately for class `A` and `B`, thus ending in two `void f(int)` functions.

This does not happen in `D` since  there the compiler knows about the `void f(int)` function as a specialization and therefore does not specialize `T` for `int`.