# C++ inheritance - ambiguous Function

Tags: c++, inheritance

I've got an Inheritance problem:
Let's say I've got

```
class Time{
protected:
void foo();
};
```

and also

```
class Base: private Time{
void foo1(){ foo(); }
};

class Child: public Base, private Time{
void foo2(){ foo(); }// here my compiler says that foo is ambiguous
};
```

why is foo() ambiguous, if the inheritance of Time in Base is private?

PS.
Just&only for those who need to see the full code, here is the GitHub Project: 
https://github.com/huntekah/Interior_decorator-OpenGL_Project/blob/master/Grafika-OpenGL/Interior_decorator/Display.cpp#L133
class Time( utilities directory ) is inherited by ControlObjects and ControlCamera, both of which are the base for Controls. Display inherits Controls , and additionally Time. commented line shows a place where SetDeltaTime() is ambiguous;

Comment: private doesn't hide it.

Comment: Because both `Base` and `Time` have a member function named `foo` and the compiler doesn't know which one you are trying to invoke. There's a dupe of this out there somewhere.

Comment: will namespace inside Base hide it?

Comment: maybe visibility is checked after scope resolution?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975291/ambiguous-when-two-superclasses-have-a-member-function-with-the-same-name-but, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158094/fixing-c-multiple-inheritance-ambiguous-call, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845854/c-multiple-inheritance-function-call-ambiguity just to start.

Comment: You may find the answers here (including but not limited to mine!) helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39042240/1858225  In short, visibility is *never* part of function-lookup and overload resolution; the compiler picks the best match *before* checking whether the function is visible from the calling context.

Comment: yaay, knowledge :3 thank you! 
btw:
Child::Time::foo() is not ambiguous

Comment: `foo()` is private. You cannot call from any derivative class.

Answer (score 1):

there's another error in your code: class base inherits privately from class Time and class Child inherits again privately from class time!!!

the law of inheritance:

```
class Time
{};

class Base : private Time
{};

class Child : public Base, private Time
{};
```

Base  has a copy of class Time because it inherits from it.

child has a copy of class Base because it inherits from it.

*** Child has a copy of class Time because its parents (Base) has this copy.

if Child tries to inherit explicitly from class Time will issue a compile-time-error: error C2584: 'Child' : direct base 'Time' is inaccessible; already a base of 'Base'

Answer (score 0):

**Preliminary remarks**

Your code snippet doesn't compile for another reason: `Base` has no access to `Time`'s `foo()` as it is a private member.  So the `foo1()` causes an error, before you have the reported ambiguity.

If you change `Time` to make its member protected, then you can reproduce your error exactly as you describe:

```
class Time{
protected:
    void foo();
};
```

**What's wrong here ?**

`Base` privately inherits `Time`, so that it's members are not expected to be visible to the outside world.

But what could be true for the external world is not true for derived classes. The name lookup rules in the case of derivation say that first the name is looked up in the class hierarchy, then overloading is applied, than only is access control carried out:

> **10.2/1** Member name lookup determines the meaning of a name (*id-expression*) in a class scope. Name lookup can result in an
>   ambiguity, in which case the program is ill-formed. For an
>   *id-expression*, name lookup begins in the class scope of this; for a qualified-id, name lookup begins in the scope of the
>   nested-name-specifier. Name lookup **takes place before access
>   control.**
>   **10.2/8** If the name of an overloaded function is unambiguously found, overloading resolution also takes place before access control.
>   Ambiguities can often be resolved by qualifying a name with its class
>   name.

As you use multiple inheritance:

```
Time     
  :
  :
Base  Time 
    \  :
     \ : 
    Child
```

So you inherit twice a `foo()`, once via private inheritance and onve via public. This ambiguity makes the name `foo` in `foo2()` ambiguous according to the standard, and before access is verified, making your code invalid.

Note that Child sees 2 foo() but ironically can't use none of them: both come via private inherited.  So even if you'd resolve the ambiguity, you'd get another error message about accessibility.